# Disable immediate file synchronisation while typing TypeScript in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, webstorm

While programming in intellij using the build-in `TypeScript` compiler, see settings below:

[image: Intellij settings]

I notice that when even typing a space, the compiler already recompiles. This on itself can be a little annoying, but combine it with `lite-server` which refreshes on file changes, your browser keeps refreshing while typing. Which slows down my development quite a lot.

With the normal `FileWatcher` you've got a setting named: `immediate file synchronisation`. When you turn this off, it doesn't recompile while typing. Unfortunately this option is missing with the embedded typescript. I could uncheck the checkbox `Track changes`, but then it doesn't compile on save any more.

Bottom line, is it possible to only compile TypeScript on save and not while typing?

Comment: Do you have file watcher for prettier or tslit? i disable it and now seems okay

Answer (score 1):

You need unchecking `Track changes` and run the compiler explicitly using Compile All button in Typescript tool window; there is no way to run the compiler on Save All

Comment: That's indeed what i mentioned in my question, but I guess you are right. Perhaps they will implement it some day

Comment: What exactly should be implemented? You can assign a TypeScript Compile All action to a shortcut of your choice in Preferences | Keymap.

Comment: @EkaterinaPrigara There is a big difference between `compile all`, and a single compilation where only one file changed. When you are developing on a relatively slow system, the recompilation while typing is a bit of a drag. My 'solution' was to transfer my projects to the `angular-cli` and only have the intellij TypeScript service on. That move was long overdue anyways :). But to get back to your question, I would like it if they implement an option where there is no `immediate file synchronisation` while using the typescript compiler. That synchronisation take place when you press 'save'.